# JavaScript: Use Replace to add space after "00" before a-z A-Z

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a form that has an input field that needs to automatically add a space between "00" and a-z or A-Z.

For instance: `"300A"` to `"300 A"` or `"200b"` to `"200 b"`

Below is the code that, I've been working on. I have done some research for some time, however with poor JavaScript skills, it took too long.

```
replace(/('00')([a-z][A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You were *really* close:

```
var str = "....whatever...";
str = str.replace(/(00)([a-zA-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

Or alternately you can use the `i` flag (ignore case):

```
var str = "....whatever...";
str = str.replace(/(00)([a-z])/gi, '$1 $2');
```

Key bits of the above:

1. Saving the result (you hadn't shown how you were calling `replace`, but not saving the result is a common error).
2. No `'` around the `00`.
3. You had two separate character classes, `[a-z]` and separately `[A-Z]`. So it was looking for `00` followed by something in the range `a-z` followed by something *else* in the range `A-Z`.

Comment: I think the quotes have to disappear also

Comment: @Tim: I just saw them, yeah, thanks. Hit refresh. :-)

Comment: Okay, I can use the alternative because the case isn't important. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3119481: Well, both would work, I just wanted to give you options. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your regexp is looking for `"3'00'aA"` Rather than `"300A"`

Try

```
replace(/(00)([a-zA-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
yourString.replace(/(00)([a-zA-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
// OR
yourString.replace(/(00)([a-z])/gi, '$1 $2')
```

You had two problems with your regex:

- `'00'` looks for the `'` characters as well as the `00`.
- `[a-z][A-Z]` looks for any lowercase letter followed by any uppercase letter. Combine the two ranges within the same set of square brackets as `[a-zA-Z]`, or just use `[a-z]` and add the `i` flag to the regex to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this for me. I better understand this. :)